# Passing a variable from a form to another in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Let's say I have custom module with Drupal.
I want to let user to type what skill their have in first form and after that show their skill as a title in second form and type percentage of their skill in textfield.

```
function skillbar_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['html5'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('HTML5'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('html5'),
    '#description' => t('Enter a percent of your HTML5 skill'),
  );
  return(system_settings_form($form));
}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: pass it from hidden field

Comment: @wild could you please tell me a little bit more ?

Answer (score 1):

[Multistep Form](https://drupal.org/node/717750) is you friend, if you are building your form using the Form API.

Otherwise there are various modules which could help you in building forms with more than one step. A couple of them being:

1. [Multi-step forms](https://drupal.org/project/mforms)
2. [Multi-Step Registration](https://drupal.org/project/step)

**Note:** Multistep forms generally collect all the data from various steps. The data is mostly submitted at the final step (which is also a best practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from one form to another through URL in the submit form of first form.

```
function skillbar_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
$data_a = $form_state['values']['html5'];

 $form_state['redirect'] = array('url_page2', $data_a);
}
```

In the other form just retrieve the data as by passing the $data_a as argument. So $var will have the value as 'html5'.

```
example_form($form ,&$form_state, $var){
  ...
}
```

And for the URL you will have to send it in items array

```
  $items['url_page2/%'] = array(

  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('page2_form', 1),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```